# Problem with return type in asp MVC Repository

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, list

I use list .Tolist() but it shows an error when return.I am use this method in asp.net MVC getaway/repository. I am also trying to find out this problem but don't find out the problem

```html
public List<Floor> GetBuildingInfoByBuildId(int floor_Id)
        {
            var result = (from floor in db.Floors
                          join c in db.Campuses on floor.CampusID equals c.ID
                          join build in db.Buildings on floor.BuildingID equals build.ID
                          where (floor.ID == floor_Id)
                          select new
                          {
                              floor.ID,
                              floor.Floor_Name,
                              c.Campus_Name,
                              build.Building_Name
                          }).Tolist();
            return result;             
        }
```

Comment: Please show the error. It will make it easier to help you then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the class object in the select statement.

```
public List<Floor> GetBuildingInfoByBuildId(int floor_Id)
    {
        return (from floor in db.Floors
                      join c in db.Campuses on floor.CampusID equals c.ID
                      join build in db.Buildings on floor.BuildingID equals build.ID
                      where (floor.ID == floor_Id)
                      select new Floor
                      {
                          floor.ID,
                          floor.Floor_Name,
                          c.Campus_Name,
                          build.Building_Name
                      }).Tolist();

    }
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: an erron show:Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: int ID, string Floor_Name, string Campus_Name, string Building_Name>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<IMS.Models.Models.Floor>'

Answer (score 0):

try this first of all you need to create a new class, for this example It will be "FloorViewModel", with the fields you need to recover from Join statement

```
class FloorViewModel
{
    public Int IdFloor {get;set;}
    public string FloorName {get; set;}
    public string CampusName {get;set;}
    public string BuildName {get; set;}
}
```

then U can get your data

```
public List<FloorViewModel> GetBuildingInfoByBuildId(int floor_Id)
{
    return (from floor in db.Floors
                  join c in db.Campuses on floor.CampusID equals c.ID
                  join build in db.Buildings on floor.BuildingID equals build.ID
                  where (floor.ID == floor_Id)
                  select new FloorViewModel
                  {
                      IdFloor = floor.ID,
                      FloorName = floor.Floor_Name,
                      CampusName = c.Campus_Name,
                      BuildName = build.Building_Name
                  }).Tolist();

}
```